# Are compilers allowed to support a feature, that is removed in the standard?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, exception-specification

In the first paragraph [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) clearly states that `throw(T1, ..., Tn)` is removed in C++17.

It confuses me, that some compilers support `throw(T1, ..., Tn)` in C++17 mode ([see demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rqq8Gv)).

- MSVC supports it by default, but you can turn on a warning for it, see [C5040](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warnings-c4800-through-c4999). It can be turned into an error with `/we5040`.
- Clang reports it as an error by default, but the error can be turned off with `-Wno-dynamic-exception-spec`.
- GCC leaves you with no choice: it's an error.

Are compilers allowed to support a feature, that is removed in the standard? For what purpose?

Or is this just a compiler extension, like `void foo(int size) { char a[size]; }` in GCC, see [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ercz8M).

Comment: There isn't a single C++ compiler that you could consider 'standard' C++ compiler, while all of them try to follow standard, there are some places where the behavior can differ. What you encountered is just one of examples where compilers differ, but Clang default behavior and GCC seem to be right into raising a compilation error.

Comment: @rustyx: Thanks, I overlooked that. I removed this part from the question, since it is clearly a typo in cppreference.com.

Comment: compilers are not bound to *only* support the c++ standard. all of these compilers have compilation options (some on by default) that don't abide by the rules. this case doesn't seem any different to me.

Comment: So what does the 'standard' standardize actually? Is there a list a compiler needs to support to be called a 'valid c++17 (or c++14/20 etc)' compiler?

Comment: @Roy2511 The "list of things it needs to support" is the standard itself. The standard standardizes the behavior of programs that want to call themselves "valid C++xx compilers", and the programs they produce.

Comment: The standard only says (in effect) that a compiler which doesn't give diagnostics where the standard requires, or gives a behaviour different from what the standard requires, does not conform with the standard. That doesn't prevent compiler vendors from explicitly supporting a different set of features, not emitting all required diagnostics, or emitting diagnostics that are not required. Compilers may also accidentally do things differently (e.g. compiler bugs).  Several C++ compilers explicitly support VLA's - a feature of some C standards, that has never been supported by a C++ standard

Comment: NOTE: [VS2019 will warn for `throw(types...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/exception-specifications-throw-cpp?view=vs-2019) if using `/std:c++17` or `/std:latest`

Comment: _Are compilers allowed to support a feature, that is removed in the standard?_  Who is going to stop them?  The ISO police have their hands full with all the Unicode encoding violations.

Comment: @Eljay: What ISO police? What Unicode encoding violations? I don't understand.

Comment: There is no ISO police.  Compilers are not "allowed" (nor disallowed); they merely have some level of conformance or non-conformance on a point-by-point basis.  If their conformance is poor, they will either have many disgruntled users or if they become popular despite (or perhaps because of) the non-conformance they will become a *de facto* "standard" (which will make the users of other compilers disgruntled with the *de facto* "standard" compiler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are compilers allowed to support a feature, that is removed in the standard?

The standard doesn't allow that. AFAIK in general it doesn't give any special treatment to features that *used to be* in the language (doesn't separate them from non-existent features).

If a compiler doesn't diagnose this error (i.e. doesn't give an error or a warning) with a specific configuration (i.e. specific flags), then it doesn't conform to the standard in that configuration.

---

> For what purpose?

Backward compatibility (what else could it be). More specifically, it lets you use both old and new features in a same translation unit.

This can be useful if you're using a library that uses a removed feature in its headers, but want to use the new language features in your own code.

Or if you want to use the removed feature in your own code along with the new features, for some reason.

---

Note that absolute conformance to the standard is not practically possible to achieve.

Some compiler vendors care about conformance more than the others. Microsoft tends to care less about it (or at least used to, they've been working on that).

Comment: MS does but the standard didn't change until C++17 allegedly on this matter so they only warn if you're using that mode or latest mode. See my comment on the OP.

Comment: I have edited your answer, and tried to answer the "For what purpose?" question as well. Is that OK? Feel free to improve that. Nobody answered "For what purpose?".

Comment: @Dr.Gut I've replaced it with my own explanation, sorry. :P You could post it as a separate answer though.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I am totally OK with that. My best hope was, that you will replace it with your own explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single answer for this.

Some things outside the Standard can be treated as pure enhancements. Some of these enhancements are suggested by the Standard ("It's implementation-dependent if X"), some are not even mentioned at all (`#include <windows.h>`).

For other things, the Standard does require that a compiler flags the violation of the Standard. But the Standard doesn't talk about errors or warnings. Instead it says "Diagnostic Required", which is understood to mean either an error or a warning. And in other cases it even says "No Diagnostic Required" (NDR), which means the compiler is not obliged to flag non-standard code.

So depending on the removed feature, it may or may not require a diagnostic. And if it does require a diagnostic, you can often tell the compiler that you're not interested in that particular diagnostic anyway.

Comment: Formally, a "diagnostic" is whatever the implementation says it is. A compiler that simply printed `!` after every compilation (successful or not) would conform if the documentation said that `!` is a diagnostic. Of course, nobody would use such a compiler. But the details of diagnostics are strictly quality-of-implementation. +1.

Answer (score 0):

> Are compilers allowed to support a feature, that is removed in the standard? For what purpose?

Compilers can do whatever they want. The C++ standard dictates rules for the C++ *language*, and while they do consult compiler vendors to ensure its rules are implementable, the vendors themselves will do what they feel is best for them and their users. Compilers have many non-standard features that developers use all the time. And I don't think *any* of these compilers fully adhere to the standard by default.

That said, I wouldn't call a compiler+settings "C++17 compliant" if they allowed *non*-C++17 code or rejected *valid* C++17 code (as dictated by the standard). Most compilers have settings that can be set if full compliance is desired.

---

If you want to be pedantic though MSVC isn't even C++11 compliant [due to lacking preprocessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019). The standard isn't everything.

Comment: If we're getting pedantic, no compiler is truly compliant due to various bugs. :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Even the standard itself has bugs. And even it has features not considered bugs, which annoy me.